# When a person deserves US$120,000 as a salary, is using some technique to pay him $100,000 ethical?

Tags: ethics, social-ethics

I wonder what "ethical" or "moral" definition or meaning can be used here.

Sometimes, we know that for a new graduate or senior software engineer, the market rate should be about $120,000 per year as the base salary at our company.

However, using some tactics, such as by asking him a "minimum salary" to begin with, or by pressuring him to accept the offer within 1.5 days so he cannot shop around, the company may be able to pay him $100,000 or even $95,000.

**Is this ethical or moral?**

I may think it is not, because you aim to underpay somebody.

However, isn't it true that whenever we buy an item, or buy a stock, we want to pay the lowest price?  When we want to remodel the kitchen, we also want to find the acceptable, good contractor so we can pay near the low price.

If that's the case, how is the company underpaying somebody any different?

The only thing I can think of is: you buy it once, perhaps they just want to have a sale or get rid of old merchandise, but if a company underpays a person, it is likely to be for two or five years. (lower base, with the same raise, it is lower later on). Moreover, if you see Peter getting $120,000 and Mike, also the same skill, same capability, same speed, but he gets only $100,000, and you don't say a word (as the HR or recruiting department), doesn't it go into the apathetic "who cares about you, Michael" category and therefore is unethical and immoral?

So my question is: is underpaying somebody for years ethical and moral?

Comment: If we want to go on full marxist, salaried work (I.e. paying people less than the value they produce) is unethical from the get go.

Comment: First, there is no assurance that the market rate itself is "fair" or "moral". It can be speculative, inflated by a fad, etc. Second, the tactic used may be coercive or deceptive, hence immoral, or may be tough bargaining that does not eliminate meaningful consent. The underpaid person can bargain back or leave. And third, one underpays somebody to save money for something else, other projects, shareholders, or, perhaps, just out of greed. How justifiable those motivations are and which way it comes out on balance is often diffused and obscure, so there is no yes/no answer.

Comment: How does a person "deserve" a particular salary, other than by entering into a contract with someone who offers to pay him that salary, and then fulfilling his own part of the contract?

Comment: @armand Marxism explicitly denies the very concept of "ethical."

Comment: @DavidGudeman if the going rate of mowing the lawn is $5, and you use technique to pay the kid $3.50, and you say, how does he "deserves it", other than if there is a contract, blah blah blah

Comment: You are trying to confuse the issue by bringing up side issues like duties that adults have toward children and the fairness of a contract negotiated out of ignorance. While it is true that people can take advantage of each other, this does not change the fact that there is no coherent concept of one person deserving a salary that no else has agreed to pay him.

Comment: I am not "trying" anything. I am just saying human dealing with another human with the intention of deceit